# Using regular expression in find_all of Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape tumblr archive, the div class tag looks like given in picture

> [image]

The class starts with "post post_micro", I tried using regular expression but failed

```
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile('^post post_micro')
```

I tried to use function in find_all for class

```
def func(x):                 
    if str(x).startswith('post_tumblelog'):
        return True
```

and used it as:

```
soup.find_all(class_=func)
```

The above works fine and I am getting what I need. But I want to know how to do it using regular expressions and why in the func(x),

```
str(x).startswith('post_tumblelog')
```

evaluates as True when the class name is starting with "post post_micro".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In BeautifulSoup 4, you can use the [`.select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) since it can accept a CSS attribute selector. In your case, you would use the attribute selector `[class^="post_tumblelog"]`, which will select `class` attributes starting with the string `post_tumblelog`.

```
soup.select('[class^="post_tumblelog"]')
```

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
soup.find_all(class_=lambda x: x and x.startswith('post_tumblelog'))
```

As a side note, it looks like you were missing a parenthesis, the following works:

```
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile('^post_tumblelog'))
```

Comment: Using .select is giving error :Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "[class^="post" and rest of the two option are working with 'post_tumblelog' but not with 'post post_micro', I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: yeah 2 of them works the lambda function and regular expression one, but the argument passed need to be 'post_tumblelog'

Comment: @sandepp - I just tested it out with the strings `post_tumblelog` and `post post_micro`, and they both worked. Do you mind posting your HTML and posting which version of BeautifulSoup you're using?

Comment: bs4 version is 4.3.2, I think it is problem with space in class values, I just picked it Beautifulsoup last night, and have no idea of css and html. So I think will have to work a little bit more